# How to remove line breaks and white space from variable in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, whitespace

I found several answers about this ([Remove ALL white spaces from text [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623231/remove-all-white-spaces-from-text))

However not one single answer has worked in my case, please take a look if you have a moment..

**1st step the Mako & Python template:** Why I have new lines and white space in the first space:

We're using Mako templates and Python to generate data in our views:

```
<!-- The Python def on the page that pulls in the correct id -->
<%def name="pull_id(contact)">
    % if "member" in contact:
        ${contact["member"]["id"]}
    % else:
        ${contact["id"]}
    % endif
</%def>

<%def name="render_contact_row(contact)">

    <!-- the def returns the id here -->
    <tr data-contact-id='${pull_id(contact)}'>
```

Originally I had the Python code directly in the `<tr>` tag however that generated visible line-breaks. Now using the `<%def` at least it keeps it all on 1 line, but there are still a couple of extra white spaces in the HTML

[image]

**Now my jQuery:**

```
$('.btn_hide').live("click", function(event) {

    // gets the id number from the data tag in html
    var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    var id = $tr.data('contact-id');

    // tried this
    id.replace(/ /g,'');

    // then this
    id.replace(/\s+/, "");

    // even this
    id.replace(/\s/g, "");

    // still prints out white space :'(
    console.log(id);

    //...
});
```

When it hits the console.log line chrome prints this out:

[image]

Obviously with line breaks and extra white space

**Finally it hits Python again:**

```
@view_config(route_name="contacts_hide", request_method='POST')
def hide(self):
    id = self.param("id")
    if id is None:
        id = self.request.body
        if id.isdigit() is True:
            id = int(id)
        if id is None:
            raise Exception("The contact id parameter cannot be null!")
```

I've been having problems with self.param, so it will skip that and hit the `id = self.request.body` line.

[image]

And of course pulls in the line breaks and extra white space :'(
[image]

Please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any of your examples will work if you assign the filtered value back to the variable:

```
var id = $tr.data('contact-id');
id = id.replace(/ /g, '');
```

However I'd recommend you to use `$.trim` method instead:

```
var id = $.trim( $tr.data('contact-id') );
```

It will remove the spaces from the start and from the end of the value.

Finally Python has `strip` method, which does exactly the same:

```
id = id.strip()
```

Comment: THANK YOU! and LOL yeah I can't believe I messed up that string = part