# How can I remove white space between words in an array using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the below array, how can I remove whitespace between words within each string? I want to convert "FLAT RATE" to "FLATRATE" and "FREE SHIPPING" to "FREESHIPPING".

[image]

I had to work out with array. I saw the solutions for simple string's case.

Comment: what did you done to make it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove ALL white spaces from text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623231/remove-all-white-spaces-from-text)

Comment: I got the solution for removing white spaces in the case of simple string, But couldn't find for array. Now, I got the answer for arrays too. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `array.map` function to loop in array and use regex to remove all space:

```js
var array = ['FLAT RATE', 'FREE SHIPPING'];

var nospace_array = array.map(function(item){
 return item.replace(/\s+/g,'');
})

console.log(nospace_array)
```

Answer (score 4):

a string can be split and joined this way:

```
s.split(" ").join("");
```

That removes spaces.

Comment: Thanks you. Worked fine

Comment: Nice! You can accept the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 2):

```js
 ['FLAT RATE', 'FREE SHIPPING'].toString().replace(/ /g,"").split(",")
```

I admit : not the best answer, since it relies on the array strings not to contain a comma.

.map is indeed the way to go, but since that was already given, and since I like chaining, I gave another (quick and dirty) solution

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need jQuery for that.

```
var ListOfWords = ["Some Words Here", "More Words Here"];
for(var i=0; i < ListOfWords.length; i++){
    ListOfWords[i] = ListOfWords[i].replace(/\s+/gmi, "");
}
console.log(ListOfWords);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the replace function to achieve this.

```
var shipping = ["FLAT RATE", "FREE SHIPPING"];

var without_whitespace = shipping.map(function(str) {
   replaced = str.replace(' ', ''); return replaced;
});
```

Comment: `"FLAT RATE AMOUNT"` => `"FLATRATE AMOUNT"`.

Comment: In that case, use a regular expression. Eg Mohammad's suggestion of `return item.replace(/\s+/g,'');`