# Javascript: String.replace for space isn't working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get rid of spaces in a string, but it seems not to be working. This doesn't return the string without spaces:

`"{   color: 'blue',".replace(" ",'')` and `"{   color: 'blue',".trim()`

I've verified that those are spaces (char code 32), and I've even done this:

`var x = "{   color: 'blue',"
x.replace(x[1],'')`

FYI, doing this in chrome's console. Am I going crazy?

Comment: `.trim()` only removes leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: I always find it weird that people mods mark questions as duplicate on SO even when the question/confusion is very different. Duplicate answers isn't the same thing as a duplicate question.

Comment: How is your confusion different than the one in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623231/remove-all-white-spaces-from-text ?

Comment: Because I didn't even realize it was removing *any* spaces. I just thought I was trapped in a waking nightmare

Comment: And you think this minor variance warrants a complete new question? Are the duplicates not useful to you? But ultimately it's not possible to satisfy everybody. I rather close more often than not often enough. Luckily I don't have the last word. If the community feels strongly about it they have ways to reopen the question.

Comment: This question is not what I feel strongly about. I'm just expressing that I wish SO had a way to distinguish "this question has answers that answer this question" from "duplicate question" markings. Its misleading in a lot of cases, and I know for a fact it causes a lot of strife in the community - especially with newbs. For what its worth, I think closing too often vs not often enough is kind of like innocent before proven guilty. Would you rather jail too many people than not enough? No. No you wouldn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does remove space, but not all of them just the first one, to remove all you should do

```js
let str = "{   color: 'blue',".replace(/ /g,'');

console.log(str);
```

Comment: ohhhhh, for crisake! Every time i run into this I curse the guy who decided replace should only do one at a time!

Comment: But wait, why doesn't trim work tho?

Comment: `/\s/g` can also use a regex and match the whitespaces, also gets tabs!

Comment: nm on trim - i'm dumb

Comment: The trim() method removes whitespace from both ends of a string. You don't have that in your string

Comment: @BT But be careful as it removes spaces from the inner strings too: `{    a: 'b    c'     }` will become `{a:'bc'}` not `{a:'b   c'}`.

Comment: this is not working for me

Comment: I discovered why it is not working for me. I am getting a float number formatted via `Intl.NumberFormat` which puts a `&8239;` character narrow non-break space instead of a normal ASCII space as the thousands separator. 

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
x= x.replace(/\s/g, '');
```