# wrong length after running replace javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate the text that you enter by an input. It consists of removing all white spaces in the chain for that use the function to replace. I hope that by removing all spaces the string remains empty ie zero length, but that does not happen if the spaces are removed but it remains of the same length. What am I doing wrong?

```
document.getElementById("Validator").onclick = function() {
 var expression = document.getElementById("expressions").value;
 var aux=expression.replace(" ","");
if(aux.length==0){
 alert("the expression contains only blank spaces");
}
};
```

Comment: Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623231/remove-all-white-spaces-from-text

Comment: Your code only removes the **first** space.

Comment: I'm an idiot, if only he replaces the first space he finds. Sorry for my nonsense questions I'm migrating a java application to javascript and I did not remember that in java I used replaceAll (). Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a literal string to the `.replace()` function for it to find (`" "`). This won't actually replace **all** spaces, it will only replace the first space in the searched string. To ensure that the entire string is searched, use a regular expression.

From **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)**:

> To perform a global search and replace, include the g switch in the
>   regular expression.

```js
document.getElementById("Validator").onclick = function() {
  var expression = document.getElementById("expressions").value;
  
  // Find one or more spaces throughout the string:
  var aux = expression.replace(/\s+/g,"");
  
  if(aux.length === 0){
   alert("the expression either contains only blank spaces or nothing was typed at all.");
  }
};
```

```html
<input id="expressions">
<button id="Validator">Validate</button>
```

Comment: I'm an idiot, if only he replaces the first space he finds. Sorry for my nonsense questions I'm migrating a java application to javascript and I did not remember that in java I used replaceAll (). Thank you.

Comment: @trokbrk No problem. Don't forget to up vote and mark as the answer.