# Ignore space changes in text field widget

Tags: javascript, dojo, textfield, dijit.form

Is there a way to ignore the spaces in the string of the text field on the 'change' event. For example `@(x) ( sin(x) )`and`@(x) (sin(x))` are treated as two different function strings, and a change event is triggered on text field change

Comment: It largely depends on context. In current form, your question provides none and is therefore unanswerable. Please create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to watch for the input changes in JavaScript, when it change it will have value, save it into a variable removing all the whitespaces, next time when value comes remove all the whitespaces and compare with previous string variable, if both are same `Do Nothing` else `Do Something`! you can find sample code [here](https://codepen.io/taksuparth/pen/qxELNj).

For removing whitespace used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623231/remove-all-white-spaces-from-text).