# Remove whitespace in a string with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get this palindrome generator to work, and I cannot figure out how to get js to remove the white space from between the words in multi-word palindromes.  race car keeps coming back false. racecar comes back true, so part of the code is working.  How do I get JS to ignore the white space between "race" and "car" so that race car comes back as true?

```
function palindrome(word) {
    var len = word.length;
    word = word.replace(/ +/g, "");


    for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor(len/2); i++ ) {
      if (word[i] !== word[len - 1 - i]) {
      return "FALSE";
       }
     }
     return "TRUE";
}

console.log(palindrome("race car"))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove ALL white spaces from text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623231/remove-all-white-spaces-from-text)

Answer (score 12):

Simply You can do this,

```js
let str = '  aaa  aa  ';
str = str.replace(/\s+/g,'');
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this code will help you

```
var str = " this is a sample "
var res = str.replace(/ /g, "");
console.log(res);

O/P - 'thisisasample'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
word = word.replace(/\s+/g, " ").trim();
```

It will remove the spaces from the front and the back as well.

Comment: You don't need to `trim()` it as your regex will match the front and back whitespaces too.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a regex before passing it to the palindrome function:

```
'race car'.replace(/\s+/, "")
```

'race car' can also be replaced by any variable containing your string.

Answer (score 1):

Hope, this helps:

```js
function palindrome(str) {
  str = str.replace(/\s+/g, ''); // Delete whitespaces.
  return str.split('') // Convert the string into an array.
    .reverse()
    .join('') === str; // Convert the array into the string.
}
console.log(palindrome("race car"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
replace(/\s+/, " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var len = word.length;
```

get the len after word change not before;

```js
function palindrome(word) {

  word = word.replace(/ +/g, "");
  var len = word.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor(len / 2); i++) {
    if (word[i] !== word[len - 1 - i]) {
      return "FALSE";
    }
  }
  return "TRUE";
}
console.log(palindrome("race car"))
```

and

```
  word = word.replace(/ +/g, "");
```

suggest use regular expression:

```
  word = word.replace(/\s+/g, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are taking `len` before removing white spaces.
So the last element you were asking returning `undefined`, that's result in no match and FALSE output.

Try following snippet:

```js
 function palindrome(word) {
          word = word.replace(/ +/g, "");
          var len = word.length;
          for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor(len/2); i++ ) {
          if (word[i] !== word[len - 1 - i]) {
          return "FALSE";
           }
         }
         return "TRUE";
    }
 console.log(palindrome("race car"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code to remove space between two words.

```
word = word.replace(/\s/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are they all using the arcane regex syntax when you can simply do:

```
word = word.replace(' ', '');
```