# Remove spaces between {{vaue}} in Mustache.js

Tags: javascript, mustache

I send `{{name}}` to my url.

```
<a href="#/{{_id}}/{{name}}/apps_details" class="app-anchor" data-appname="{{name}}" data-appid="{{_id}}"data-filtercriteria="{{filtercriteria}}">

URL='/:id/:name/apps_details'
```

But in here if `name=test one` then url not go to desire page. I think space between "test" and "one" cause to this. so how to remove this spaces in `{{name}}` parameter.

I want to remove spaces in `{{name}}` not some string value.`.replace(/\s+/, "")` cannot use to do that

Comment: You cannot do that in the frontend side (except with vanilla JS post tampering). You need to do it on the serverside

Comment: what about using `encodeURI(name)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove ALL white spaces from text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623231/remove-all-white-spaces-from-text)