# Find the indexOf of a string which contains spaces or any special characters

Tags: javascript, string

```js
var value = '1 552 222';
var searchText = '22'
if (value.includes(searchText)) {
  console.log(value.search(searchText)) //6
  console.log(value.indexOf(searchText)) //6
}
```

Here both prints 6 but the actual index should be 4 since the first occurrence of 2 is in the second group of numbers(552).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're matching `22` and expecting answer as you're matching `2`

Comment: You want to get '22' but 2 2 its not the same

Comment: The first occurrence is in "222". All spaces are taken into account. JavaScript considers all characters as full-fledged characters of the string, it doesn't know you don't want to count whitespaces. So, you have to get rid of whitespaces first and then apply those functions.

Comment: Here you can find some examples of how to get rid of spaces: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623231/remove-all-white-spaces-from-text/6623263

Answer (score 0):

So you want to search the string as though the spaces or special characters don't exist, but you want the index to be given as though they do exist.

To do that, you'll need to implement your own search algorithm.

```js
const value = '1 552 222';
const searchText = '22';
const excludes = ' @!#'; // the characters to exclude (including spaces)

console.log(getIndex(value, searchText));

function getIndex(str, search) {
  return search ? str.split("").findIndex((c, i) =>
    c === search[0] &&
    clean(str.slice(i), excludes).startsWith(search)
  ) : 0;
}

function clean(str, toRemove) {
  return str.split("")
    .filter(c => !toRemove.includes(c))
    .join("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[From the link](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```js
var value = '1 552 222';
var i = 0, strLength = value.length;
for(i; i < strLength; i++) {

  strLength = value.replace(/\s/g,'');

}

var y=strLength.indexOf('22');
console.log(y);
```