# How to search text and ignore spaces in text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a following jQuery which searches text in table rows and it works fine. The issue is that I would like to ignore/remove spaces when searching some text e.g.: I want to find this in a table:

```
'John Smith'
```

but when I type in search bar: *Johnsmith* then record is not found. So I would like to remove spaces in my jQuery code to find any text ignoring spaces. Here is my jQuery with commented code which removes spaces but it doesn't work:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#search').keyup(function() {
        search_table($(this).val());
    });

    function search_table(value) {
        $('table .rows').each(function() {
            var found = 'false';
            $(this).each(function () {               
                //if ($(this).text().replace(" ", "").toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
                if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
                    found = 'true';
                }
            });

            if (found == 'true') {
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: `.toLowerCase().replace(/ +/, "")` (Replace one or more space with `""`)

Comment: How to remove spaces in a string is not a difficult topic to search for. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623231/remove-all-white-spaces-from-text

Comment: String.replace doesn't "replaceAll" the way you used it.

Comment: In many languages `"1 2 3 4".Replace(" ", "") == "1234"` - so a reasonable expectation, but not in javascript (and a quick test would have shown it not working as expected).  No need for the `+` just `.replace(/ /g, "")` will suffice.

Comment: Slightly relevant:  you might also like to remove spaces from your search input otherwise someone searching for "john smith" will not find "john smith"!

Comment: @freedomn-m that's a very good remark! I've just amended my code and it works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.replace(/ /g,"")` to replace all spaces (groups of spaces)

```
            if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(/ +/g,"").indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
                found = 'true';
            }
```

Comment: No need for the `+` just `.replace(/ /g, "")` will suffice.  (no reason *not* to have it, just adding some info)

Comment: @freedomn-m, yes you have right thanks for the precision..