# How can I join a the string of array inside an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

How could I join a string inside an array of array? I'm trying to remove the space between inside array.

This is the array sample.

```
[
  [ 'time' ],
  [ 'user full name' ],
  [ 'affected user' ],
  [ 'event context' ],
  [ 'component' ],
  [ 'event name' ],
  [ 'description' ],
  [ 'origin' ],
  [ 'ip address' ]
]
```

I'm trying this to become like this.

```
[
  [ 'time' ],
  [ 'userfullname' ],
  [ 'affecteduser' ],
  [ 'eventcontext' ],
  [ 'component' ],
  [ 'eventname' ],
  [ 'description' ],
  [ 'origin' ],
  [ 'ipaddress' ]
]
```

This is my function i'm trying to run

```
const MakeArrayToSmall = (headerRow) => {
        let arrayToCheck = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < headerRow.length; i++) {
          let lowercaseLetter = headerRow[i].toLowerCase().split();
          arrayToCheck.push(lowercaseLetter)
        }
        return arrayToCheck
      
      };

      
      const samplearray = MakeArrayToSmall(headerRow)
      console.log(samplearray)
```

Comment: Is it fair to say that you would like to remove all whitespace, including interior whitespace, from a string?  If so, this may be a duplicate of [Remove ALL white spaces from text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6623231/1563833)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop the `headerRow` and then select the first element in the inner array and replace whitespaces with empty string `headerRow[i][0].toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "")`

```js
const MakeArrayToSmall = (headerRow) => {
        let arrayToCheck = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < headerRow.length; i++) {
          let lowercaseLetter = headerRow[i][0].toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "");
          arrayToCheck.push(lowercaseLetter)
        }
        return arrayToCheck
      
      };
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to split the string with a space character as a delimiter and then join the resulting array without any delimiter to remove the spaces.

```js
// ...rest of your code
let lowercaseLetter = headerRow[i][0].toLowerCase()
                                     .split(' ') // <--- split on space
                                     .join(''); // <-- join
```

A shorter version of the working code:

```js
const MakeArrayToSmall = (headerRow) => {
  return headerRow.map(item => [item[0].toLowerCase().split(' ').join('')]);
};

const headerRow = [
  [ 'time' ],
  [ 'user full name' ],
  [ 'affected user' ],
  [ 'event context' ],
  [ 'component' ],
  [ 'event name' ],
  [ 'description' ],
  [ 'origin' ],
  [ 'ip address' ]
];

const samplearray = MakeArrayToSmall(headerRow);
console.log(samplearray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code.
Explanation:
Since there is array inside an array. map traverses the outer array and provides access to inside array each time .the inside array has only one element we can access it via `e[0]` then we perform replace using regex.
For more information you can put console statements whereever you find its hard to understand.

```js
let x = [
  [ 'time' ],
  [ 'user full name' ],
  [ 'affected user' ],
  [ 'event context' ],
  [ 'component' ],
  [ 'event name' ],
  [ 'description' ],
  [ 'origin' ],
  [ 'ip address' ]
]
let z= x.map(e=> {
    let y = e[0].replace(/\s/g,'')
    return [y];
})

console.log(z)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) method.

example:

```
const arr = [
  [ 'time' ],
  [ 'user full name' ],
  [ 'affected user' ],
  [ 'event context' ],
  [ 'component' ],
  [ 'event name' ],
  [ 'description' ],
  [ 'origin' ],
  [ 'ip address' ]
]
const result = arr.flatMap(x => [[x[0].toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "")]])
console.log("result", result)
```

*only one level is flattened:* 
*arr1.flatMap((x) => [[x * 2]])* will return your two dimensional array;

Answer (score 0):

I don't why, but when I run your codes, I get this as a result. When I run this part.

```
let lowercaseLetter = headerRow[i][0].toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "");
```

result

```
[
  't', 'u', 'a',
  'e', 'c', 'e',
  'd', 'o', 'i'
]
```

And then I tweak it a little bit and it works when i run this. And I get the result I'm looking for.

```
let lowercaseLetter = headerRow[i].toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "");
```

Can someone explain me why remove the ***[0]*** works? I'm so confused