# How to check for empty value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, null

I am working on a method of retrieving an array of hidden inputs in my form like so

```
<input type="hidden" value="12:34:00" name="timetemp0">
<input type="hidden" value="14:45:00" name="timetemp1">
<input type="hidden" value="15:12:00" name="timetemp2">
<input type="hidden" value="16:42:12" name="timetemp3">
<input type="hidden" value="16:54:56" name="timetemp4">
<input type="hidden" value="17:03:10" name="timetemp5">
```

My javascript function retrieves these individually by using getElementsByName('timetemp'+i)

```
    for (i ; i < counter[0].value; i++)
        {
//finds hidden element by using concatenation of base name plus counter

var timetemp = document.getElementsByName('timetemp'+i);

//if there is a value alert that value to user - this is just for testing purposes at the moment
//because there is only one of timetemp.i then it occupies position 0 in array
            if (timetemp[0].value == null)
            {
                alert ('No value');

            }
            else
            {
                alert (timetemp[0].value);

            }
}
```

So what should happen is it will alert the user of the value in that hidden input but if it comes accross an input with no value like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="timetemp16">
```

Then it will say "No value"

However th if function cannot seem to work with this:

I have tried:

1. `(timetemp[0].value == null)`
2. `(timetemp[0].value === null)`
3. `(timetemp[0].value == undefined)`
4. `(timetemp[0].value == '')`

It always seems to default to else clause.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try just `if (timetime[0].value)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript might help

Comment: @Richard D you solution worked perfectly! I wish i could give you the points, could you answer my question maybe and i will accept your answer?

Comment: Very strange that your code didn't work when you did `.value == ''`. [Here's your code](http://jsfiddle.net/v8kC6/), only replacing the counter with a fixed number. It works fine.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Comment as an answer:

```
if (timetime[0].value)
```

This works because any variable in JS can be evaluated as a boolean, so this will generally catch things that are empty, null, or undefined.

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, using "if(value)" to judge a value whether is an empty value is not strict, because the result of "v?true:false" is false when the value of v is 0(0 is not an empty value). You can use this function:

```
const isEmptyValue = (value) => {
    if (value === '' || value === null || value === undefined) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, I would check what `i` gets initialized to, to see if the elements returned by `getElementsByName` are what you think they are. Maybe split the problem by trying it with a hard-coded name like `timetemp0`, without the concatenation. You can also run the code through a browser debugger ([FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/), [Chrome Dev Tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html), [IE Dev Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565622%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Also, for your if-condition, this should suffice:

```
if (!timetemp[0].value) {
    // The value is empty.
}
else {
    // The value is not empty.
}
```

The empty string in Javascript is a falsey value, so the logical negation of that will get you into the if-block.

Answer (score 1):

Your script seems incorrect in several places.

Try this

```
var timetemp = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i = 0; i < timetemp.length; i++){
    if (timetemp[i].value == ""){
        alert ('No value');
    }
    else{
        alert (timetemp[i].value);
    }
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/FSzT2/

Here's what I changed:

1. started by getting all the `input`s via `TagName`.  This makes an array
2. initialized `i` with a `var` and then looped through the `timetemp` array using the `timetemp.length` property.
3. used `timetemp[i]` to reference each `input` in the `for statement`

Comment: YOU ARE WRONG why would i want to find all inputs, I have over 50 inputs in my form , I only want to find timetemp0, timetemp1, timetemp2 - this does not adapt to this!

Comment: Fair enough @sqlmole.  But no need to yell.  I am only trying to help you.  I answered based on your question, which does not mention other inputs.

Comment: For other elements/attributes, the `.length` errors out on null. I ended up modifying it to be like this: `return (${jsElement} && ${jsElement}.length > 0)`

Answer (score 0):

The counter in your for loop appears incorrect (or we're missing some code). [Here's a working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TpwYj/12/).

**This code:**

```
//Where is counter[0] initialized?
for (i ; i < counter[0].value; i++)
```

**Should be replaced with:**

```
var timeTempCount = 5; //I'm not sure where you're getting this value so I set it.

for (var i = 0; i <= timeTempCount; i++)
```

Comment: How do you know OP needs to validate for XHTML? The `/>` isn't an absolute requirement.

Comment: Im using HTML5, but thanks for the code example incase i use XTHML 1.1 in the future

Answer (score 0):

here's oneliner for checking for any values presented in array (null, undefined, '' in this case)

```
const isEmptyValue = val => [null, undefined, ''].includes(val);
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged at stackoverflow. Please also explain what the code does.