# Is ''.charAt(0) reliably ''?

Tags: javascript

I know that there are better ways to check for an empty string—bear with me.

---

This is *not* checking for empty string in general. I'm actually doing something like:

```
var s = /*who knows?*/;
switch (s.charAt(0)) {
    // ...
}
```

and wanted to know if I can avoid having to do an extra `if (!s)`.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript

Comment: No. I am not checking for empty string.

Comment: Maybe then you should elaborate your question.

Comment: Check out this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript

Comment: @luxun I have no idea what you're checking for then.

Comment: Just one tip: `charAt` will fail when `s` is not of type string, other than that it's 100% "safe" as Mike said in his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as long as the value is a valid string.  Section 15.5.4.4 of the [language spec](http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.4.4) says

> 1. Let position be ToInteger(pos).
> 2. Let size be the number of characters in S.
> 3. If position < 0 or position ≥ size, return the empty String.

That was not changed since ES3.  Interpreters are pretty good around string function compatibility.

That said, I recently implemented a peephole optimization for `charAt` to [Closure compiler](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/PeepholeReplaceKnownMethods.java#604) but I did not optimize out of bounds checks because the compiler tends not to optimize what are considered programmer errors.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will always return `""` if the index exceeds the length of the string.

Taken from [MDC's documentation of the `charAt()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt):

> Characters in a string are indexed from left to right. The index of the first character is 0, and the index of the last character in a string called stringName is stringName.length - 1. **If the index you supply is out of range, JavaScript returns an empty string**.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the modified question (or what I think the question is):

If your variable is undefined or not of type `string`, then `.charAt` will fail.

Do something like

```
if (typeof s == "string") {
    switch(s) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Or using the `===` operator to avoid type conversions. (An empty string will also compare equal to false, empty list, zero, and whatever else given the weird conversion rules.)

Comment: `switch ("string" === typeof s && s.charAt(0))` will also work.  The `default` case will fire when `s` is not a string.