# If statement not triggering alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a if statement that triggers a alert box if there is text in the div.

My Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D7cPT/21/

My HTML:

```
<div id="post-preview">aasasdasd</div>
```

MY JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Bind it to some action.
    if{$('#post_body_html').html();) {
       alert('asdasda');
      }
});
```

Comment: Is this your real code? `if{` is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: Looks syntactically invalid at first glance.  Double check what you wrote.  I see a left brace after the if keyword that looks suspicious, as well as the semicolon in the test expression.

Comment: Why is your IF statement winking at me?

Comment: this code just makes me think of lisp.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OH DEAR GOD:

```
//why is there a bracket after the if and a semicolon in there?
if{$('#post_body_html').html();) {
```

How about:

```
//change if{ to if( and remove semicolon
if($('#post_body_html').html()) {
```

Also your selector doesn't match the ID of your element. Change `#post_body_html` to `#post-preview`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D7cPT/23/)

**Edit:**

To those who land here later on, a better way to accomplish the same test is written:

```
if($('#post_body_html')[0].childNodes.length) {
```

instead.

Comment: I love the 'lightbulb' moment where we try to pretend that that was the biggest thing wrong with that code - :P we all gotta start somewhere.

Comment: Note that `.html()` is foolish, you probably want something like `[0].childNodes.length` instead

Comment: @Raynos added to answer, just in case.

Answer (score 3):

Try this ->

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Bind it to some action.
    if($('#post-preview').html()) { // wrong ID and wrong syntax
       alert('asdasda');
     }
});
```

Working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/D7cPT/25/

Answer (score 0):

You have MANY problems:

1. It should be post-preview, not #post_body_html
2. You have if { instead of if (
3. You end your if statement with a semi-colon? Huh?
4. html() doesn't return a bool, it returns a string.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Bind it to some action.
    if ($('#post-preview').html().length > 0) {
       alert('asdasda');
      }
});
```

Comment: An empty string would evaluate the `if` statement to false. `.length > 0` is not *really* necessary. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript)

Comment: True, it's only necessary for my sanity ;)

Answer (score -3):

You should remove the `;`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Bind it to some action.
    if{$('#post_body_html').html()) { //line changed
       alert('asdasda');
      }
});
```

Comment: except that if still has a bracket after it...`if{`