# Check if an HTML input element is empty or has no value entered by user

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript) question here. Can I check if an element in the DOM has a value or not? I'm trying to put it into an 'if' statement and not sure if my approach is correct. Here goes:

```
if (document.getElementById('customx')){
    //do something
}
```

Or should it be:

```
if (document.getElementById('customx') == ""){
    //do something
}
```

EDIT: By value I mean, `customx` is a text input box. How can I check if this field has no text entered.

Comment: Define "value". You mean text content? child elements? A `value` attribute?

Comment: What do you mean by value? `<input type="text" value="myValue">` or `<span>myValue</span>`?

Comment: Hi, sorry I should have been more explicit in my question. I've updated my question

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The `getElementById` method returns an Element object that you can use to interact with the element. If the element is not found, `null` is returned. In case of an input element, the `value` property of the object contains the string in the value attribute.

By using the fact that the `&&` operator short circuits, and that both `null` and the empty string are considered "falsey" in a boolean context, we can combine the checks for element existence and presence of value data as follows:

```
var myInput = document.getElementById("customx");
if (myInput && myInput.value) {
  alert("My input has a value!");
}
```

Comment: @simon Works fine on Chrome for me. Remember that you cannot access the elements of the document object until the DOMContentLoaded event has fired https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

Comment: thank you let me check out and I have problem I will going to tell you

Answer (score 9):

getElementById will return false if the element was not found in the DOM.

```
var el = document.getElementById("customx");
if (el !== null && el.value === "")
{
  //The element was found and the value is empty.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var input = document.getElementById("customx");

if (input && input.value) {
    alert(1);
}
else {
    alert (0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Empty is not the same as "no value".

`HTMLInputElement.value` is `''` when you have an invalid entry. If `.value` is not `''`, then it's not empty. That's definite, but since there are times when `.value === ''` but not empty, we need to test. For example, in Chrome, with a `number` input type, if you type `.` or `e` it will be placed in the input box, but `.value` will not change from `''` because it's invalid.

```html
<input type=number>
```

We can ask the browser for more information and thankfully `ValidityState` is extremely well supported. Basically, if there's no value, but the browser says there's a bad input, then it's not empty.

```js
function isInputEmpty(input) {
  return !input.value && !input.validity.badInput;
}
```

Edit: Credits to @osullic for find this in spec:

> A control's value is its internal state. As such, it might not match the user's current input.

[https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#a-form-control's-value](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#a-form-control%27s-value)

Comment: This is an interesting answer, but it would be good if you could link to some reference. I'd like to be sure that I can really rely across standard browsers that `HTMLInputElement.value` doesn't change from '' unless what's been entered passes validation.

Comment: The spec does indeed seem to match what you say: [https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#a-form-control's-value](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#a-form-control's-value)

Comment: @osullic Thanks for the reference. I discovered this because I'm trying to implement `HTMLInputElement` with Web Components and am trying to closely follow spec. There's a way to detect with `:placeholder-shown`, but you need a placeholder (even if blank) and then that can affect text selection. `badInput` seems more compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Your first one was basically right. This, FYI, is bad. It does an equality check between a DOM node and a string:

```
if (document.getElementById('customx') == ""){
```

DOM nodes are actually their own type of JavaScript object. Thus this comparison would never work at all since it's doing an equality comparison on two distinctly different data types.

Comment: The first one is not correct either. It checks whether the element exists, not whether it has a value.

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
if (document.getElementById('customx').value === ""){
    //do something
}
```

The `value` property will give you a string value and you need to compare that against an empty string.

Comment: Keep in mind that `" "` is different to `""` but hard to spot on screen.

Comment: Be aware that this crashes if the element does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myInput = document.getElementById("customx");
if (myInput.value.length > 0) {
  //do something;
}
```

(`.length > 0` is another way to check the input element)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added some context to make it clear what your solution brought to the table; in the future add some context for a higher quality answer. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some tips.