# How to add class to an element when both inputs have value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to add a class active to the element `go_back_right` when both inputs with classes `search_box_name` and `search_box_id` have any value. I have tried referencing to the answers that are already on this platform, but I had no luck, as I'm new to js. Any help?

```css
.go_back_right:active {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.05);
  animation: status 4s ease forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="search_box_container">
  <input class="search_box_name" id="search_bar username" for="username" name="username" type="text">
  <input class="search_box_id" id="search_bar roomNamehtml" name="room" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: [`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) isn't a class.  You *probably* just want `.active` and `$(".go_back_right").addClass("active")`

Comment: @freedomn-m How about the condition to check if there are values inside?

Comment: Oh... thanks! It's working now.

Comment: @m4n0 go for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is jQuery snippet to set an event for adding/removing class

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    setEvents();
    $('.search_box_container').trigger('change');
});
function setEvents() {
    $('.search_box_container').on('change', function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            search_box_name = $this.find('.search_box_name').val().trim(),
            search_box_id = $this.find('.search_box_id').val().trim();
        if (search_box_name && search_box_id) {
            $('.go_back_right').addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('.go_back_right').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It works, however, I have to click somewhere on the screen to make it work. Any way to make it work as soon as both inputs get value?

Comment: @DenisKviatkovskij Update `.on('change')` event to `.on('keyup')`, and `trigger('change')` to `trigger('keyup')`. It would work immediately

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```js
function setClass() {
  if (document.querySelector(".search_box_name").value != "" && document.querySelector(".search_box_id").value != "") {
    document.querySelector(".go_back_right").setActive();
  } else {
    document.querySelector(".go_back_right").setActive(false);
  }
}
setClass();
```

```css
.go_back_right:active {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.05);
  animation: status 4s ease forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="search_box_container">
  <input oninput="setClass()" class="search_box_name" id="search_bar username" for="username" name="username" type="text">
  <input oninput="setClass()" class="search_box_id" id="search_bar roomNamehtml" name="room" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Your css `:active` doesn't match class `.active`.  Your snippet gives `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null`.

Comment: Works, however, I want changes to appear as soon as value is put in. Without having to click somewhere on the screen.

Comment: ive changed `onchange` on `oninput`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add an additional class to the element with the class `.go_back_right` right? If so, add this to your JS file:

```js
const searchBoxName = document.getElementByClassName('search_box_name');
const searchBoxId = document.getElementByClassName('search_box_id');
const goBackRight = document.getElementByClassName('.go_back_right');

const addClass = () => {
  if (searchBoxName && searchBoxName.value && searchBoxId && searchBoxId.value) {
    goBackRight.classList.add('active');
  }
}

addClass()
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803412/check-if-an-html-input-element-is-empty-or-has-no-value-entered-by-user/8803494), [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp) and [this](https://www.developintelligence.com/blog/2016/04/css-class-vs-id-which-one-to-use/) for more info and btw, you can't have two or more elements having the same id like that `search_bar` id you have on both your inputs.