# Test if text has been entered into search box

Tags: javascript

I have a table which has a search box. I want to check if the text search box has a text value entered in it before performing the "table.row" line (as this just returns the first line in the table if empty, which i don't want). I have tried using .value and .count but couldn't get it working. Is there a better way to test if the user has entered text in the box?

```
    #locTable_filter input {
        border-radius: 5px;
        width: 300px;
        font-size: x-large;
        text-align: center;
    }


        $('#table_filter input').bind('keyup', function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {              
                if (count > 0) {
                    //TODO check that Search has some text in it.
                    $(table.row({ search: 'applied' }).node()).click();
                }
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803412/check-if-an-html-input-element-is-empty-or-has-no-value-entered-by-user

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if an HTML input element is empty or has no value entered by user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803412/check-if-an-html-input-element-is-empty-or-has-no-value-entered-by-user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .val() function in jquery. Here's the code:

```js
$('#table_filter input').bind('keyup', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        if ($(this).val().trim() !== '') {
            $(table.row({ search: 'applied' }).node()).click();
        }
    }
});
```