# Go to url if value is null

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, attr

I have a form, an input and a link. If the input has no value, clicking the link would direct to a certain url. If the input is NOT empty, then the click would have to submit the form. This is how the link looks like:

```
<li class="youtube"><a href="#">YouTube</a></li>
```

This is what I have so far in Jquery:

```
$('.youtube').bind('click', function() {
    if($(input).val() == ''){
        $(".youtube a").attr("href", "http://www.youtube.com/")
    }else{
      $(form).attr("action","http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=");
      $(form).submit();
    }

});
```

This doesn't work, I can't figure out why.

Comment: is your input a textbox?

Comment: @Adam Sweeney No its not, why do you ask?

Comment: input seems a bit broad; shouldn't you use something like `if ($!('input:textbox').val("");` If it was a textbox at least that would point to textboxes; should give the input an ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to be targetting the  link rather than the li

I.E.

`$('.youtube a').bind('click')` etc..

Also have you got multiple input fields? Your input field needs to be in quotes otherwise you're targetting a variable, i.e. 'input'

To check for an [empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript) i'd just do:

```
if(!$('input').val())
{
    // Rest of code here
}
```

So your full code would be:

```
$('.youtube a').bind('click', function() {
    if(!$('input').val()){
        $(".youtube a").attr("href", "http://www.youtube.com/")
    }else{
      $('form').attr("action","http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=");
      $('form').submit();
    }

});
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that earlier.. It's the same case as with the input field, you need to put quotes round the `$(form)` to make it `$('form')` otherwise you'll again be targetting the variable 'form' - I've corrected my answer to reflect the correct solution.