# How to display a progress status/spinner when outputting file via Response.ContentType, Response.End?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cookies, httpresponse

I have a webform with a **Download LinkButton**, on the button's click event I'm fetching data and then **generating an .XLSX file** for download. During the generation of the file, **Response.Clear()** is called, **Response.ContentType** is set and eventually **Response.End()** is called.

I need to **display a spinner .gif** during that operation. Once the file has been generated and the file "Open/Save" dialog pops up, the **spinner should not display**. Unfortunately, since I'm changing the content type and calling Response.End there is no response returned back to the page to work with.

**Can anyone please provide a little help with this scenario?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually ended up going with a solution that **did not require the use of an iFrame**. Instead I make use of a **Cookie**, which the file generation process writes into it simple a Name Value pair. This cookie can then be checked later from the client side via JavaScript to determine when the response (.xlsx file) has completed.

The result should be that the loading spinner image should display until the .xls file has been **generated and returned** to the client (Cookie contains the **DownloadComplete=true** Name Value pair).

1. In the **OnClientClick** event for the **LinkButton**:

   ```
   function startFileDownload(){

   // Set Timout for calling checkState function again
   setTimeout(checkState, 1100);
   setCookie('DownloadComplete', '', 1);

   // Download is starting, Hide Download LinkButton
   document.getElementById('<%= btnDownloadExcel.ClientID%>').style.display = "none";

   // Display progress spinner
   var img = document.getElementById("image1");
   img.src = "Images/99.GIF";
   document.getElementById('image1').className = "spinnerDisplay";
   }
   ```
2. Here is the JavaScript code for the **checkState** function:

   ```
   function checkState()
   {
       var img = document.getElementById("image1");
       var finished = getCookie("DownloadComplete");
       // Check to see if download is complete 
   if (!isEmpty(finished)) {
       setCookie('DownloadComplete', '');
       // Download is complete, Hide progress spinner
       img.className = "spinnerHide";
       document.getElementById('<%= btnDownloadExcel.ClientID%>').style.display = "";
   } else {
       // Refresh progress spinner, Set Timout for calling checkState function again
       img.src = "Images/99.GIF";
       setTimeout(checkState, 1100);
   }
   }
   ```
3. Here is the JavaScript code for the **setCookie** and the **getCookie** functions:

   ```
   function setCookie(cName, value){
   var now = new Date();
   var time = now.getTime();
   time += 3600 * 1000;
   now.setTime(time);
   document.cookie = cName + "=" + value 
   + '; expires=' + now.toGMTString() + '; path=/';        
   }

   function getCookie(cName)
   {
       var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
       for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
       x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
       y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
       x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");

       if (x == cName) {
           return unescape(y);
       }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Then on the server side in the class that generates the .xlsx file, after clearing the HTTP Response **add a Name Value pair to the Cookie**:

   ```
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();

    // Append a cookie that will tell the browser the file has finished processing 
    // and is included in that stream (note specific path must match same path for cookie set in JavaScript)            
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("DownloadComplete", "true");
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60);
    cookie.Path = "/";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
    //Other code here to specify the MIME type, setup the HTTP header 
    //and Response.BinaryWrite out the file
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
   ```

Comment: Explained in detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-do-you-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript/3261380#3261380

Answer (score 0):

It should go like this : (one solution among others)

1) create an iframe on your page which will actually download your file ( so your main page wont be blank )

2) Add a cookie to the response. via

`Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=1.jpg");`

3) when a user press "download" you set (via js) the src for the iframe to download the file. and you show the spinner. after this , you start reading via setInterval  , if theres a cookie. if thereis - the download has finished so you can hide the spinner.