# Check if input is empty with jquery

Tags: jquery

There are several ways to check if a input is empty, for example:

```
$('input:text').val().length == 0
```

My problem is that i found no solution how to check if the input is empty **or** blank?
How can i check this is there some regex?

Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to `trim()` it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you check for an empty string in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-do-you-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript)

Comment: biziclop is right, just do `$('input:text').val().trim().length == 0`

Comment: If you are not explicitly looking for a jquery solution, input has a pattern attribute which you can use. The regex is the same as javascript's

Comment: @schopy could you please explain it further?

Comment: @JohnSmith Basically you can have client-side form validation without using js on modern browsers. You can have a look at the Constraint Validation chapter at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms_in_HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove white spaces before checking empty:

```
if ($("input:text").val().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "").length == 0){
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [jQuery.trim()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) to trim your input first:

```
var value = $('input:text').val(); 
if ($.trim(value) == '') { /* Empty or blank */ }
```