# checking for empty string in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have

```
<table id="table1">
 <tr>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I check for the value in  using

```
$('#table1 tr').find('td').eq(0).text()
```

this equates to `" "`

so the check is

```
$('#table1 tr').find('td').eq(0).text() == " "
```

While transferring the file to server, a garbage value is inserted between quotes

```
$('#table1 tr').find('td').eq(0).text() == " A "
```

using     `$('#table1 tr').find('td').eq(0).text().trim()` also gives `" "` as the cell contains `&nbsp;`

How do I prevent this garbage value from being inserted each time I deploy on server

Comment: @user3292653: This is a different question with a different problem. Please read the question again.

Comment: How are you transferring the file to the server? *What* does insert the garbage?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-do-you-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Maybe not too soon

Comment: @pramod.nikam.dev: Have you read the question and the comments?

Comment: @abhitalks: This is standard procedure. Only if the community agrees, your question gets closed.

Comment: @user544079: You need to explain in the question more about "*While transferring the file to server...*" and "*...each time I deploy on server*".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/), try to set [HTML()](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Try this, for setting value in Table Cell (TD).

```
$('#table1 tr').find('td').eq(0).html("A");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#table1 tr').find('td').eq(0).html() == '&nbsp;'
```

solved the above issue

Answer (score -1):

Try to check:

```
$.trim($('#table1 tr').find('td').eq(0).text()).length
```

The trim() will help you here.

Comment: the cell contains a &nbsp;. So length comes out 1. How to check for &nbsp;

Comment: Please try this. $.trim() will remove the extra space. Have you tried this code?