# Cannot set the property of an object when passing parameters in the costructor

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I need to set up two flags `canPlayLive` and `isSubscribed` to `true` or `false` accordingly to values of parameters sent when creating the object.

Basically when `null`  `undefined` `''` is passed I want the flag on `false`, otherwise on `true`.

Using the following code flags are always on `true`.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
function MyStation(id, chId, name, hdImg, subscribedFlag, liveEntryId, liveUrl, timeLists) {
    this.id = id;
    this.dataId = chId;
    this.name = name;
    this.imageUrl = hdImg;
    this.subscribedFlag = subscribedFlag;
    this.liveEntryId = liveEntryId === null || undefined || '' ? null : liveEntryId;
    this.liveUrl = liveUrl === null || undefined || '' ? null : liveUrl;
    this.timeLists = timeLists;
    this.canPlayLive = this.liveUrl === null || undefined || '' ? false : true;
    this.isSubscribed = subscribedFlag == 0 ? false : true;
}

var test = new MyStation(
0,
'x123',
'foo',
'url',
0,
null,
'',
[]
);

console.log(test);
```

Comment: Read up on JS syntax. You need to do `liveEntryId === null || liveEntryId === undefined || or liveEntryId ===''`, but wouldn't `!liveEntryId` work just as well?

Comment: Agreed - `!liveEntryId` would cover all bases.

Comment: ```!liveEntryId``` erroneously results in ```true``` if it is equal to ```0``` or ```NaN```

Comment: To be fair, so would `liveEntryId === null || liveEntryId === undefined || or liveEntryId ===''`

Comment: @sahbeewah - incorrect: both `0` and `NaN` are falsies, i.e. resolve to false when coerced to a boolean state.

Comment: @Utkanos Note the negation operator (!). That is the point I was trying to point out, and therefore is not a valid solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since canPlayLive is dependent on liveUrl you should write your code as follows:

```
if (liveUrl ) {
   this.liveUrl = (liveUrl == '') ? null : liveUrl;
}
```

**Explanation:**
when parameter liveUrl is null or undefined the result will always be false otherwise true.
Since you want that also empty string will be considered as null we need the second condition.

When this.liveUrl having the correct value let's go to canPlayLive variable:

```
 this.canPlayLive = this.liveUrl || false;
```

**Explanation**:
When this.liveUrl is null it is considered as false, hence the result will be false.

when this.liveUrl is NOT null it is considered as true, hence true or false will always give us true.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem using `!liveUrl` instead of `''`.

```
function MyStation(id, chId, name, hdImg, subscribedFlag, liveEntryId, liveUrl, timeLists) {
    this.id = id;
    this.dataId = chId;
    this.name = name;
    this.imageUrl = hdImg;
    this.subscribedFlag = subscribedFlag;
    this.liveEntryId = liveEntryId === null || undefined || !liveEntryId ? null : liveEntryId;
    this.liveUrl = liveUrl === null || undefined || !liveUrl ? null : liveUrl;
    this.timeLists = timeLists;
    this.canPlayLive = this.liveUrl === null || undefined || !liveUrl ? false : true;
    this.isSubscribed = subscribedFlag == 0 ? false : true;
}
```

Comment: useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-do-you-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript