# Trap Error when checking parameter

Tags: javascript

Simple Question really.  I have a JS function that accepts a passed parameter.  On the chance that the passed value is NULL I want trap for it but my limited JS experience is causing me to not have the proper syntax.  Here it is.  What do I need to do to change the syntax?  There is more to the function obviously but the rest of it works fine when I don't trap for the NULL. The bad syntax is on the last line and I know it has to do with using a reserved word but I am not sure how to make it work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //Pass UserName from text box on form to Ajax call 
  function CheckUserName(UserName_element) {

      var UserName = try { UserName_element.value; } catch (e) { };
```

For those of you asking:   It is a js function inside of a vbscript Sub (unfortunately the whole site is written in classic asp)

```
    Sub UserNameValidation_Entry()
%>
<div id="username_validation" style="width:15px;position:relative;float:right;">
<img id="valid_UserName_image" src="<%=UrlForAsset("/images/tick.png")%>" border="0" style="display:none;" alt="User Name is Available." 
    title="User Name is Avaliable." />
<img id="invalid_UserName_image" src="<%=UrlForAsset("/images/icon_delete_x_sm.png")%>" border="0" style="display:none;" alt="User Name Already Exists." 
    title="User Name Already Exists." />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

        //Pass UserName from text box on form to Ajax call 
      function CheckUserName(UserName_element) {

          var UserName = UserName_element.value; 
          var UserName = try { UserName_element.value; } catch (e) { };


        $j.ajax({
            data: { action: 'CheckUserName', p_UserName: UserName },
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'page_logic/_check_username_ajax.asp',
            success: function (result) {

                //If user exists return X out, if not return green checkmark
                if (result == "True") {
                    try { valid_UserName_image.style.display = "none"; } catch (e) { };
                    try { invalid_UserName_image.style.display = "inline"; } catch (e) { };
                }
                else {
                    try { valid_UserName_image.style.display = "inline"; } catch (e) { };
                    try { invalid_UserName_image.style.display = "none"; } catch (e) { };
                    }
                }
            }
        );
        //return false;
    }
</script>
```

Called from here.

```
           <tr class="required_field">
            <td class="empty"></td>
            <td><b>Username:</b></td>
            <td class="label_value_separator"></td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' name="username" size="24" maxlength="50" value="<%=Session("s_username") %>" onblur="CheckUserName(this);">
                <% Call UserNameValidation_Entry() %>

        </tr>
```

Comment: What do you want your function to do if username is null? Also can you provide example of how you call `CheckUserName`?

Comment: When won’t you be sure whether the textbox exists?

Comment: Learn how to use try/catch: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/trycatch.shtml -- such blocks do not return values.  You can't say `var UserName = try...` as in your example, it's a syntax error.

Comment: Why do you wrap everything in try-catch blocks? They should be very rarely needed.

Comment: try catch is mostly used in javascript for native errors.. for example JSON.parse, or eval.. Is rare to throw intentionally errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As minitech alludes to, you probably don't need to try/catch this scenario. That's only really an issue when attempting to access an object property that might be `"undefined"`, or when you are trying to parse JSON that might be invalid, etc.

It would be sufficient simply to

```
if ( username !== null ) {
  // Send AJAX request
} else {
  // Send error to UI
}
```

There are many other JavaScript null-like detection patterns [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-do-you-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript).

Comment: Thanks everyone, the wrapping in try catch was a requirement from the boss, I was not originally using them.  Could just be a standard here.  I will go with the above suggestion.  It seems simple enough.

Comment: If it's a requirement, wrap the above in a try? Bit lol-worthy but won't do anything.