# Display DIV in if/else statement

Tags: javascript

I have a filter in place, 
`if` the filtered results for criteria is  `>0`, i get the results displayed. In the case where the criteria itself returns an empty list, well, i'll juts get an empty list `else`,  i returns all items.

Id' like to adapt my code so that if a criteria is selected  but outputs an empty  list, it should rpint on screen a DIV initially set in `display:none`

I am thinking about putting an `if/else` statement within the second `else`, but could not get the right syntax...or may be it is juts a bad idea ?

```
.filter('selectedDishType', function() {
    return function(dishes, dishTypes) {
        console.log(dishTypes);
        if (dishTypes.length > 0) {
            return dishes.filter(function(dish) {
                return dishTypes.indexOf(dish.dishCategory.toLowerCase()) != -1;
            });
        } else {

            return dishes;

        }
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

create a small function which check dishType and call that function in if condition.

```
function isEmpty(dishType) {
    return (dishType && dishType.length > 0);
}
```

For checking value is blank or not please refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-do-you-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript)

Comment: thanks Nehal, though I dont' see where to embeed the function as I am  just beginning in JS .