# ReferenceError: event is not defined on addEventListener()

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I keep getting this error when I try to load an HTML doc I'm working on:

> ReferenceError: event is not defined.

It points to the `addEventListener()` line in the JavaScript of the document. I am trying to **AVOID** jQuery if at all possible. Hence my use of `document.getElementsByClassName().addEventListener()` instead of `$(".className").click()`.

Furthermore, I would also like confirmation to this question:

1. Is `addEventListener()` a valid method to call from `getElementsByClassName()`, or...
2. Will I need to use the `forEach()` method to attach the `addEventListener()` method to each element object one at a time?

Relevant JavaScript (very incomplete because it is supposed to make some major divs appear/disappear, and I'm implementing that functionality dead last after all content has been added to the page):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("NavbarButton").addEventListener(
    "click",
    JumpToSection(event.target.innerHTML)
);

function JumpToSection(Section)
{
    /*
        TO DO:
        Figure out how to toggle visibility of main sections
        The selected section needs to have visibility turned on & all others turned off
        May be doable with a loop and an if-else statement
    */
    
    // Set the URL to include the viewed section ONLY IF the function's input parameter is NOT BLANK
    // EXTREMELY optimized solution found here:
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-do-you-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript
    if(!!Section) location.hash = Section;
    
    // Make sure the page is scrolled to the top
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
    
    // To be used a bit later on for looping through the sections & toggling visibility
    var AllSections = document.getElementsByClassName("Section");
}
```

And the bit of HTML where I'm trying to add the event listeners (right now, I'm testing on only one of the Navbar buttons; once it works I can remove the `onclick=""` attributes from the others):

```
<div id="TopBar" class="grid_32">
    <div id="CharName" class="grid_8 alpha">Calyo Delphi</div>
    
    <ul id="NavBar" class="grid_24 omega">
        <li id="ImagesButton"  class="NavbarButton grid_6 alpha">IMAGES</li>
        <li id="DetailsButton" class="NavbarButton grid_6"       onclick="JumpToSection(this.innerHTML)">DETAILS</li>
        <li id="FormsButton"   class="NavbarButton grid_6"       onclick="JumpToSection(this.innerHTML)">FORMS</li>
        <li id="StatsButton"   class="NavbarButton grid_6 omega" onclick="JumpToSection(this.innerHTML)">STATS</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have searched other questions similar to this here on Stack Overflow, but it seems like I've already passed the event into the called function like I should be doing? So I don't know what I've missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript you have to attach event to every node return by `getElementsByClassName`

Like this

```
var classes=document.getElementsByClassName("NavbarButton");

for(var i=0;i<classes.length;i++)
    classes[i].addEventListener('click', JumpToSection);

function JumpToSection(event){
  console.log(event.target.innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: `JumpToSection` function returns `undefined`. Your code will fail the same way the OP's fail.