# How to check if an object is empty? [javascript]

Tags: javascript, object

I need to evaluate if an object is empty.

For example suppose I have an object:

```
var home = ....;     // this is an object and after I print it

console.log(home)    // the result of this option is []

//now I need to check if a object is empty or null
if( home == null || home == undefined )
{
    // I don't know specify how object is empty
}
```

How can I detect whether or not the above object *home* is null/empty?

Comment: `!!home.length` ??

Comment: Your example is an array, not an object fwiw.

Comment: @Andy Array is an object. :)

Comment: Don't confuse the OP. You know what I mean.

Comment: if I try home.length gives me an error "length is undefined"

Comment: @user6045391, add the code for `home` to your question. `home.length` should work unless you're actually using a JS object (not an array) which needs an alternative method to check whether it's empty.

Comment: @Andy I do home.length and I obtain "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"... I print console(typeof home) and I get object what I must do?

Comment: Add `home` to your question. Is it `var home = []` or `var home = {}`?

Comment: cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-do-you-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

To check for an empty array

```
if (!arr.length) {
  // if the array is empty
}
```

and for an object (check that it has no keys)

```
if (!Object.keys(obj).length) {
  // if the object is empty
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1u1a425o/)

Comment: I use all two method and I have the same error, but the vector that I use it is result from var vet = $(this).find('...').map(function() {
     return {
      'name': this.id,
      'value': this.value
     };
    }).get();

Comment: when the fields are the value the problem doesn't exist,but when I leave the fields empty I have this problem!

Comment: At the risk of repeating myself, add the relevant code/HTML to your question. You're now asking about jQuery which doesn't get a mention in your question. If you don't give us all the information, how can we help you?

Answer (score 0):

Only way I see so far may be `({}).toSource() === o.toSource()`

Example:

```
var y = {a: 't'};
window.console.log(({}).toSource() === y.toSource());
delete y.a;
window.console.log(({}).toSource() === y.toSource());
```

EDIT : Oh, nicely found, Andy.