# JS how to check empty String and Space

Tags: javascript, appcelerator-titanium

Help me pls

```
if(value == ""){
// do anything
}
```

but I need to check space " " (2,3,... space is include) is the same way of empty String

ps. sorry in my English

Comment: @Andrew - It's not a duplicate at all.  That other question has nothing to do with detecting strings containing only spaces.

Comment: @RJM There are numerous answers on that question that handle: null/undefined and only-whitespace input. See, for example, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3261380/279608)

Comment: sorry man I need to check String with whitespace only is same as empty String

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A regex can easily solve this problem.

```
if (/^ *$/.test(value)) {
    //string contains 0+ spaces only
}
```

If you need to include null also, then add `!value ||`.

If you need to include newlines, tabs, and the like, then use `/^\s*$/` for the regex.

Comment: Why regex and not `if (!value || !value.trim()) { //null or empty }`. Matches empty strings, tabs, newline characters

Comment: @pcvnes That works fine too