# form validation javascript functions

Tags: javascript, function

i wonder if any body can drop for me the difference between the following javascript functions because am confused of which one i can use.
THESE ARE THE SNIPPETS BELLOW:

```
function isEmpty(){}
```

and

```
function isBlank(){}
```

thank you in advance!

Comment: They only have different names? I am not sure how you would use them as they do nothing.

Comment: I have found this. I hope it will help you.
[how-do-you-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-do-you-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript)

Comment: If you really want to know what they do differently, you have to show the function definitions, not just the names. From the names, I would guess that `IsEmpty()` is only true if the field is totally empty, while `isBlank()` will be true if the user has typed spaces into the field, but nothing. else.