# Password and confirm password validation in javascript error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
var password = document.getElementById("password");
var confirm_password = document.getElementById("confirm_password");

function validatePassword()
{
  if(password.value != confirm_password.value)
  {
    confirm_password.setCustomValidity("Passwords Don't Match");
  } 
  else if(password.value=='')
  {
    password.setCustomValidity("Passwords must not be empty");
  } 
  else
  {
    password.setCustomValidity('');
  }
}
password.onchange = validatePassword;
confirm_password.onkeyup = validatePassword;
```

```html
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Please Enter Password" required="required"/>
<input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password"  required="required"/>
```

I need to show password empty message while submitting without typing anything.
It validates mismatching but it is not validating empty fields. Any solution?

Comment: else if(password.value=='' || password.value==null)

Comment: also note that using the required attribute will cover this validation on most modern browsers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you check for an empty string in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-do-you-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

It must be in this sequence. 
Check empty value first. try this

```
    if(password.value=="")
    {
        password.setCustomValidity("Passwords must not be empty");
    } 
    else if(password.value != confirm_password.value)
    {
        confirm_password.setCustomValidity("Passwords Don't Match");
    } 
    else
    {
        password.setCustomValidity('');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using like this, with `||` (or) condition,

```
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Please Enter Password" required="required"/>
<input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password"  required="required"/>

<script>
    var password = document.getElementById("password");
    var confirm_password = document.getElementById("confirm_password");

function validatePassword()
{
    if(password.value != confirm_password.value)
    {
        confirm_password.setCustomValidity("Passwords Don't Match");
    } 
    else if(password.value == '' || password.value == undefined || password.value == null)
    {
        password.setCustomValidity("Passwords must not be empty");
    } 
    else
    {
        password.setCustomValidity('');
    }
}
password.onchange = validatePassword;
confirm_password.onkeyup = validatePassword;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not setting the `setCustomValidity()` inline in your `<input>` tag, you can remove even your `required` attribute and leave all your validations to your JS script **(just make sure you handle your `submit event` properly, e.g. with `e.preventDefault()`)**. This is to avoid the default validation from triggering. Secondly, in your logic, your `password.setCustomValidity('');` is not resetting at all each time either one of the above two conditions is met.

So for your case, to be safe, try this:

**Remove the `required` attribute and add the `oninput` attribute:**

```
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Please Enter Password" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" />
```

The `oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"` will ensure the custom validity is reset each time you edit the password. Then in your JS code:

```
function validatePassword()
{
    if(password.value.trim() == "")
    {
        password.setCustomValidity("Passwords must not be empty");
        password.reportValidity();
    } 
    else if(password.value != confirm_password.value)
    {
        confirm_password.setCustomValidity("Passwords Don't Match");
        confirm_password.reportValidity();
    }; /* else
    {
        password.setCustomValidity("");
    } */
}
```

Note that if you don't change the sequence of your logic, the `"Passwords must not be empty"` can never be triggered whenever the `confirm_password` has value -- although it can still trigger the `mismatch` error. It only works when **both are empty**.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `.reportValidity()` for the warning will actually show up.

```js
var password = document.getElementById("password");
var confirm_password = document.getElementById("confirm_password");

function validatePassword()
{
    if(password.value != confirm_password.value)
    {
        confirm_password.setCustomValidity("Passwords Don't Match");
        confirm_password.reportValidity();
    } 
    else if(password.value.trim() == "")
    {
        password.setCustomValidity("Passwords must not be empty");
        password.reportValidity();
    } else
    {
        password.setCustomValidity("");
    }
}
password.onchange = validatePassword;
confirm_password.onkeyup = validatePassword;
```

```html
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Please Enter Password" required />
<input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" required />
```