# How to define a variable in JavaScript that is empty but gives true for a if condition

Tags: javascript

```js
var a = '';
if (a) {
  console.log("True Value");
} else {
  console.log("False Value");
}
```

The above code logs "False Value" for obvious reasons, I want to set variable 'a' to a empty value such that it return true when used  with if and logs "True Value".

Setting 'a' to empty object/array works fine but, I also want to do comparison between two variables but that is not possible with objects as they are compared by reference and not value.

Also I can not change the if else condition as it handles many cases other than this.

Comment: `if(a != undefined)`

Comment: Which line of your code do you think we can change?

Comment: actually the code in which I have to use this concept has many cases and I cant change the code just for this specific case.

Comment: Definitely not the if else code

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-do-you-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you check for an empty string in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-do-you-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript)

Comment: _I can not change the if else condition_ You want us to help change your code, **without** actually changing anything?

Comment: I think the rule is we can only change the assignment of `a`.  The rest of the code is off limits.  I am not sure what "empty" means though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you worded the question correctly. this will check if the value is not `null` or `undefined` therefore any other falsey value will evaluate to true in the if statement. eg. `[]`, `0` and `false` will pass

```js
var a  = '';
if(a != null){
  console.log("True Value");
}else{
  console.log("False Value" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this?

```
// allow empty values inside, but false if undefined
if (typeof a !== 'undefined') {
  // true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your if else condition or assignment of var 'a' because **we can't change javascript behavior**.
It will always consider empty string as falsy value!

I hope it works for you

```js
var a = '';
var a = (a) ? false : true;
if (a) {
  console.log("True Value");
} else {
  console.log("False Value");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OP, I infer your requirements to be:

1. Cannot change any Javascript code, only the contents of `a`
2. The code snip must output "True Value".
3. Must be a value type.
4. Must be "empty," whatever that means.

Anyway how about this:

```js
var a = '\0';  //Null
if (a) {
  console.log("True Value");
} else {
  console.log("False Value");
}

alert("See? It's empty. No space.>>>" + a + "<<<");
```