# Checking the input if its empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am pretty new to jQuery so I have a problem with this.
I am trying to check if input is empty by jQuery. I have this script:

```js
$('#submit').click(function(){
  if($.trim($('#username').val()) == ''){
    alert('Input can not be left blank');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="username" id="username" type="text" placeholder="Enter your Username"/>
<button class="btn btn-info btn-block login" name="submit" id="submit" type="submit">Create an Account</button>
```

Thanks for reply.

Comment: You didn't state what your problem is.

Comment: What's your actual question?  "How should I best check if a string is empty in Javascript"?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-do-you-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript

Comment: It seems that your code is working. What is the problem?

Comment: My problem is that if I click the button the alert doesnt show up.

Comment: I see the alert if I run the code in this post.

Comment: You can see from the snippet in your question that this works fine. If you have issues with it I'd suggest you check the console for errors

Comment: Or it's possible that you did the thing with your browser to suppress alerts.  You should try it using console.log instead.

Comment: It is working fine for me. Have you added the validation script before jQuery file?

Comment: The snippet here works for me as well.
I have no idea why it doesnt work on my site.

Comment: You could search a bit before asking this question, this has been answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-do-you-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the length property to determine if it's empty:

```js
if ($.trim($('#username').val()).length > 0) {
// not empty
}
```

Edit:
Removed white spaces  `$.trim`

Comment: This doesn't account for whitespace only input, like the OP is removing with the trim.  Edit: and you have an unclosed '(' in your code.