# How to Return False When Input Doesn't Same or Empty in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

i want to show `alert` and `return false` when **the password** and **confirm password** doesnt same or when the password is empty.

here what i try.

```
<div class="card margin-card-password">
    <div class="card-header">Change Password</div>
        <div class="card-body">
        <form id="change_password" name="change_password" method="get" action="action/save.php">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="New Password">New Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Confirm Password">Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirm_password" value="">
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="change_password" name="change_password">Save</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#change_password').on('click', function(){
       var password = $.trim($("#password").val());
       var confirmpassword = $.trim($("#confirm_password").val());
       if(password != confirmpassword) || (password.includes ("")){
           alert('The Password is Doesnt Same!');
           return false;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Any errors in console? Possible extra space in `password.includes ("")` might be causing trouble?

Comment: The "empty string" is in every string, hence `.includes()` makes not much sense.

Comment: `id="confirm_password"` identifiers must be unique on DOM

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you check for an empty string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-do-you-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript)

Comment: @GeorgeBailey ah, im not see my form and button have same id. ok,

Comment: You should not trim passwords, a space is a valid password character.

Comment: @Xorifelse ok, already remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`password.includes ("")`
This part of code checks if password *contains* **"" - empty string**. Every **string** *contains* **empty string**. You need to check if string *is* an empty string like this - `password == ""`.

Hope this will help You

```
  $('#change_password').on('click', function(){
       var password = $.trim($("#password").val());
       var confirmpassword = $.trim($("#confirm_password").val());
       if(password != confirmpassword || password == ""){
           alert('The Password is Doesnt Same!');
           return false;
       }
    });
```

And this

```
$('#change_password').on('click', function(){
    var password = $.trim($("#password").val());
    var confirmpassword = $.trim($("#confirm_password").val());
    if(password != confirmpassword){
        alert('The Password is Doesnt Same!');
        return false;
    }else if(password == ""){
        alert('The Password is empty!');
        return false;
    }
});
```

P.S. Sorry for bad English

Comment: @Andreas yeah indeed. so i can learn more where and why its wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As your password variable is already assigned as the input value, change password.includes("") to the following:

```
password.length == 0
```

As a note, I'd recommend that your alert should read as 'Incorrect password' for easier readability.