# Vue2 v-show validate empty strings in a loop

Tags: string, validation, vuejs2, is-empty

How do I validate  inside of a loop with `v-show` empty items with vuejs2. I was trying the following but without any results

```
<div v-for="user in $store.state.users.data">
   <ul>
       <li v-show="user.mobil !== null ||  user.mobil !== ''" >
              <a v-bind:href="'tel://' + user.mobil"> <i class="fa fa-mobile-phone"></i> <span>{{ user.mobil }} </span></a>
       </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: How does your `$store.state.users.data` look like?

Comment: `$store.state.users.data` is an array of objects fetched from server

Comment: Can you make an example array with 2,3 of those objects with same structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare like `v-show="user.mobil"`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    users: [{
        mobil: '123',
        name: 'Foo'
      },
      {
        mobil: '',
        name: 'Bar'
      },
      {
        mobil: null,
        name: 'Baz'
      },
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="user in users">
    <ul>
      <li v-show="user.mobil">
        {{user.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

- [How do you check for an empty string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-do-you-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript)