# Alerting user while submitting if mandatory inputs are not filled

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am a Python developer and I have been working on Vuejs app.

If have function that is equivalent of `a()` in python that takes iterables. and if all items in iterable are  true than `all([...])` returns `true`

```
methods: {
    all: function(iterable) {
        for (var index = 0; index < iterable.length; ++index) {
            if (!iterable[index]) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

and here is how I validate.

```
 if (this.all([
                        this.age,
                            this.gender,
                            this.contactNumber,
                            this.townCity,
                            this.department.name,
                            this.attendType
                        ])
                ) {
                    window.location = "#slip"
                    this.displayState = 'block';
                }
                else{
                    alert("Please fill all required fields.");
                }
```

but this is not working.

Even if I fill all the mandatory fields I have the values in all the this.* attributes still I get alert saying "Please fill all required fields."

Answer (score 1):

In JS, empty string values will return false on your IF statement.
You should check this point first.

(Maybe you have to check [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-to-check-empty-undefined-null-string-in-javascript))

Other thing : **Make sure your "departement.name" variable is assigned. Vuejs is not reactive with sub-properties in objects.**

[Reactivity In Depth (Vue.js)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)