# What is the acceptable concise way to check for null or undefined in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, null, undefined

If you need to check whether a value is set i.e. not `undefined` or `null`, what would be the most convenient way to do it that does not sacrifice readability?

Here are some of the options I have been using:

1. Clear and exact but long:
   `if (value !== null && value !== undefined) {...}`
2. Short, exact but not clear
   `if (value != null) {...}`
3. Short, not exact and not clear 
   `if (!value) {...} // true with 0, NaN and empty string`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check empty/undefined/null string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-to-check-empty-undefined-null-string-in-javascript)

Comment: just take the first. it checks both unwanted values.

Comment: @tim: Not really, that question is more about checking an empty string, in this case, I want to check if the value is `null` or `undefined`. But thanks anyway!

Comment: @NinaScholz: Yes, the first one is correct (and so does the second one). I just wonder if there are better way in terms of readability to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

`undefined` is a data type for javascript so it is necessary to validate `undefined` as well as empty or null value like this:

```
if (!value && value !== undefined) {...}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I'm asking for. I want to find a way to check if a value is not `null` or `undefined`. The solution you proposed, while getting rid of `undefined`, doesn't filter `null` value.