# How to test for `0` and `false` in TOML files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I would like to be able to check TOML files for undefined or empty strings. So in the below example `0` and `false` should have returned that they have been set, where `test4` is clearly not defined, but the checks [from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3261380/256439) says they are, which is wrong.

**test.js**

```
const TOML = require('@iarna/toml')
const fs = require('fs');

const f = TOML.parse(fs.readFileSync('test.toml', 'utf-8'))
console.log(f)

function isEmpty(str) {return (!str || 0 === str.length)}
function isBlank(str) {return (!str || /^\s*$/.test(str))}

console.log(isBlank(f['test1']))
console.log(isBlank(f['test2']))
console.log(isBlank(f['test3']))
console.log(isBlank(f['test4']))

console.log(isEmpty(f['test1']))
console.log(isEmpty(f['test2']))
console.log(isEmpty(f['test3']))
console.log(isEmpty(f['test4']))
```

**test.toml**

```
test1 = 0
test2 = false
test3 = ''
```

which gives

```
{ test1: 0, test2: false, test3: '' }
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
```

I am guessing the problem is related to the TOML parser is being clever, as it understands `0` is an integer and `false` is a boolean.

## Question

How can I make a test function `isNotSet()` that for the given TOML file will return?

```
false
false
true
true
```

or
true
true
false
false

depending on your take in the problem.

Comment: do you mean something like `function isNotSet(str) {return !!(str ?? false)}` checks ONLY if the string is `null` or `undefined`. returns false if the string is `undefined` or `null`

Comment: I suppose that would work. I get `Unexpected token ?` when I try your function.

Comment: what node.js version do you have, it seems it doenst support https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Comment: It is v10.19.0, but if it is an issue, I could upgrade to latest lts.

Comment: MDN says 14.0.0 is needed

Answer (score 1):

```
function isSet(str) {return (str === undefined || str === null || str === '')}
```

which gives

```
false
false
true
true
```

where you can extend it with extra checks as needed.