# Add condition to a html form`

Tags: html

I have the following simple HTML code and want to add a condition, like if fname <> a then display a
comment "Wrong first name". I have the following code and am unsure where to put the conditional
code. Please help as I am new to HTML!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" `enter code 
    here`"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<h2>HTML Forms</h2>
<form action="">
<label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value=""><br>
<label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value=""><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
    If fname <> a Then //This is where I go wrong!
    alert("Condition met")
    end If
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't add conditions in HTML only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check for an empty/undefined/null string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-can-i-check-for-an-empty-undefined-null-string-in-javascript)

Comment: for server side which language you are using like php or anything else?

Comment: You need to use Javascript to do that. Go through the above link you can find how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.

```
<form action="" onsubmit="myFunction()">
    <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value=""><br>
    <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value=""><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
<script type="text/javascript">
   function myFunction(){
     var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
     if(fname == '<>')
        alert("Condition met")
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[HTML Inputs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) have some *basic* validation that you can implement with their input attributes, like the [`maxlength`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefmaxlength), [`minlength`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefminlength), [`size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefsize), or the [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern) attribute that takes a regular expression (if you are familiar with them).

```
<input type="text" pattern="a" name="fname" id="fname" />
```

This will force the user to submit *exactly* the letter "a" as name (just an example of course! You should write a more useful regex).
In case of invalid input, the browser will display an error message.

If you want to go further, and have full control over the (client-side) validation, then you need JavaScript.

```
<script>
    const nameInput = document.getElementById('fname');

    if (nameInput.value !== 'the_value_to_check_against') {
        alert('Incorrect name');
    }
</script>
```

### Learn more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation).

PS: This may not work if you are not using HTML5. If it is your code, I suggest you use HTML5 by replacing the first line (. Remove the xmlns attribute in the  and also remove the two other .