# Unable to perform validation using null || undefined || "" values

Tags: javascript

I have one validation that I need to perform. When a string is `null` or `undefined` or `""` I need to show a message like "*unable to perform further steps*". If I *do* have values I need to proceed with further validations. I tried below code, but it doesn't work.

```js
function test(){

  var value = undefined; // api returns undefined

  if(value != "" || value != undefined || value != null){
     alert("ID::: " + value);
     //next validations      
  }else{
    alert("Id is blank, we are unable to process the request!!!");   
    return false; 
  }

}
```

```html
<button type="button"onclick="test()">Click</button>
```

Comment: Use `&&` instead of `||`

Comment: When the value is `undefined`, the logical OR `!= null || != undefined` returns `true` because currently it **is** `undefined` but it is **not** `null`. You need to use AND instead.

Comment: `null == undefined` so no need to check seperately

Comment: also if this is input validation just doing `""` is not gonna work you have to test for more then one spaces as well

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-can-i-check-for-an-empty-undefined-null-string-in-javascript) for more tips.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function test(){

  var value = undefined; // api returns undefined

  if(value != "" && value != undefined && value != null){
     alert("ID::: " + value);
     //next validations      
  }else{
    alert("Id is blank, we are unable to process the request!!!");   
    return false; 
  }

}
```

```html
<button type="button"onclick="test()">Click</button>
```

Comment: Just write `if (value) { ... } else { ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `!someVariable` converts to a boolean and handles those checks automatically

```js
function test(){

  var value = undefined; // api returns undefined

  if(!value){
    alert("Id is blank, we are unable to process the request!!!");   
    return false; 
 }

 alert("ID::: " + value);
 //next validations  

}
```

```html
<button type="button"onclick="test()">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```js
function test(){

  var value1 = undefined; // If api returns undefined
  var value2 = null; // If api returns null
  var value3 = ""; // If api returns empty string
  var value4 = 45; // If api returns any value
  
  examineValue(value1);
  examineValue(value2);
  examineValue(value3);
  examineValue(value4);
      
}

function examineValue(value) {
  if(value === "" || value === undefined || value === null){
    alert("Id is blank, we are unable to process the request!!!");   
    return false;
  }
  alert("ID::: " + value);
  //next validations  
}
```

```html
<button type="button"onclick="test()">Click</button>
```