# Why don't DOM my events work and style changes?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

First of all, let me tell you my purpose. If the entry is blank, a divin will appear, but when something is typed the divin will be "display: none".
I want this to happen, but as shown in the video, I tell me not to press the delete key if the input value is blank and it works, 3 words and "I deleted the number 8" only appeared 3 times on the screen recording. Strangely, when the delete key is pressed slowly, the divim successfully "display: block", but when I hold my finger without pulling it (I tried it in the key press event) it doesn't do that. You can check all the codes on my github account. Full code: https://github.com/BerkayAkgurgen/Film-ProjectAPI/tree/main
[Screen Record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nX3A8.gif)

```
// key event
searchInput.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
        let control = false
        if (e.which == 8 && searchInput.value.trim() == "") {
            control = true
        } else {
            control = false
        }
        if (control) {
            e.preventDefault()
            return
        }
        console.log(e.which);
    })
```

```
where I check empty input 
if (inputValue == "" || !isNaN(inputValue)) {
        ui.clearInput()
        ui.returnBack()
    } else {
        filmRequest.getDatas(inputValue)
            .then(data => {
                ui.displayResults(data)
                ui.resultUI()
            })
    }
```

```
// Style Changes
returnBack() {
        this.mostPopulerHeader.style.display = "block"
        this.topParents.style.display = "grid"
        this.resultHeader.style.display = "none"
        this.resultParent.style.display = "none"
    }

    resultUI() {
        this.mostPopulerHeader.style.display = "none"
        this.topParents.style.display = "none"
        this.resultHeader.style.display = "block"
        this.resultParent.style.display = "grid"
    }
```

Comment: So you're wondering why the results are blank afterr they showed up properly at first?

Comment: wait you want it to show blank only when there are 8 characters or less not 3?

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem, if you could explain clearer. It seems to work for me.

Comment: @AndersKitson When the entry is blank, I get a "not found" warning. When the entry is blank, movies that say "Top 10 Movies" should appear.

Comment: As I said, press and hold the delete key to delete it. Weird, don't delete the characters slowly, but try to delete it by holding it down as it appears in the video.

Comment: ok I see the issue now, let me take a look

Comment: hmm... so that api key ran out, but I tried to create a new one and it said it was activated, but it doesn't work. Have to debug futher. Not sure how to resolve at this point

Comment: API key is working. I am still using it right now and I do not see any other errors. If you see what you see, I would appreciate it if you let me know.

Comment: Not sure if it would work but try `if (inputValue.trim() == "" || !isNaN(inputValue)) {` instead

Comment: or you could try `if (!inputValue|| !isNaN(inputValue)) {`

Comment: Doesn't work but thanks for trying.

Comment: Try reading this see if it makes sense, it should be checking when that value is empty and rendering your top 10 UI https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-can-i-check-for-an-empty-undefined-null-string-in-javascript