# How to check if the value of id is empty or null? using react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I just want that if the **valuesToSubmit.personID** or **valuesToSubmit.dataID == ''** is empty , it will
enter to `if condition` and if not it will go to `else`

```
if (valuesToSubmit.personID == '' || valuesToSubmit.dataID == ''){
   console.log("the value you've submit is empty")
}else{
 console.log("the value you've submit is not empty")
}
```

this is the result when i tried to alert valuesToSubmit.personID (empty)

[image]

and this is the result when i send some value

[image]

this is the result in the console.log() when i tried to enter empty id
( **valuesToSubmit.personID** )

```
{}
```

Comment: Lots of ways to go about this. You could define a helper function `function isNotEmptyOrNull(inputString) { }` which you can then re-use, or you could use the double negation operator (`!!valuesToSubmit.personId || !!valuesToSubmit.dataID`), or you could explicitly check (`if ((valuesToSubmit.personID === null || valuesToSubmit.personID === '') || (valuesToSubmit.dataID === null || valuesToSubmit.dataID === '')) {`, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check for an empty/undefined/null string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-can-i-check-for-an-empty-undefined-null-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

This question is not particular about ReactJS but about JavaScript. Therefore, you should retag the question.

To give an answer to your question:

It depends what value the parameters take when the the user doesn't give an input. The usual options are an empty string `''`, `null` or `undefined`, so checking for `falsy` values should do it:

```js
if (!valuesToSubmit.personID || !valuesToSubmit.dataID){
 console.log("the value you've submit is empty")
} else {
 console.log("the value you've submitted is not empty")
}
```

Besides, you should (always) make use of the strict equality operator `===` for equality comparison as this avoids unwanted type coercion.

Comment: your condition is wrong, when i tried this, even if i select have value, it always go to else

Comment: `valuesToSubmit.personID` is false if the value is 0, '', undefined or null - so this part of the condition is wrong, but he pointed out correctly that you should use === for your check

Comment: still not entering the if condition

Comment: The check I provided jumps into `if` if both values are `falsy`. I recommend reading up on truthy/falsy in JavaScript. If `else` is executed, this means values are present. You can try to output the values with `console.log()` to see what's in there.

Comment: the result of `console.log` is `{}`

Comment: For which value? `personID`, `dataID` or the complete `valuesToSubmit` object? JavaScript considers `{}` as a truthy value.

Comment: the `valuesToSubmit `

Comment: Then you do not even have attributes in the object. Is this the intended behavior if no values are set by the user? If so, you can add a condition to the start of the if statement to check if the object is empty: `!Object.keys(valuesToSubmit)`.