# How to convert request file to base64 string in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64, multer, image-upload

I have file coming in request.file object. If I `console.log(request.file)`
It prints

```
{
  fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: 'Screenshot from 2021-06-23 18-34-25.png',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/png',
  destination: 'public/assets',
  filename: 'file-1628356843810.png',
  path: 'public/assets/file-1628356843810.png',
  size: 620962
}
```

Now I want to convert file to base64 string and I did

```
  const encoded = request.file?.buffer.toString("base64")
  console.log(encoded)
```

It says

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check for an empty/undefined/null string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-can-i-check-for-an-empty-undefined-null-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score -3):

```
const fs = require('fs');
// read binary data of the file
const binaryData = fs.readFileSync(request.file);
// convert binary data to base64 string
const base64String = new Buffer(binaryData).toString('base64');
```

Comment: Don't only post code as an answer but provide an explanation of what your code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: The code clearly had comments before each line.

Comment: Please see the comments.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question at hand. Please take some time to elaborate on your answer. Explain some things like *how* it solves the problem.

Comment: This answer in fact has nothing to do with the question...