# How to replace a null/blank in Google form response from Apps script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a code that checks for the answers in a Google Form, and if they match, it sends an email. The below code is working fine only if there is a value entered in the form. Since this is not a mandatory question, sometimes it can be blank.

I added the below line to handle the null, but it is failing:

`thisQuestion5 = allQuestions[5] !=null? allQuestions[5] : 'no answer';`

Below is the error I'm getting:

[image]

This is the code:

```
    function getAnswer() {
    var allQuestions,
    i,
    itemType,
    L,
    thisAnswer,
    thisQuestion,
    itemType5,
    thisAnswer5,
    thisQuestion5,
    number_of_submissions;

number_of_submissions = FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponses().length;

allQuestions = FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponses()[number_of_submissions-1].getItemResponses();

L = allQuestions.length;

thisSubmissionsAnswers = [];

thisQuestion5 = allQuestions[5] != NULL ? allQuestions[5]:'no answer';
//Get this question

itemType5 = thisQuestion5.getItem().getType();
//failing at this line when there is a blank value

FOR question 5 IF(itemType5 = = = FormApp.ItemType.PAGE_BREAK) { };

thisAnswer5 = thisQuestion5.getResponse().toString();
//Get the answer Logger.log(thisAnswer5);

let htmlMsg = thisAnswer5
  
  IF(thisAnswer5 === 'Incident Reported')
   {GmailApp.sendEmail('abc@gmail.com', 'Incident Reported', '', { htmlBody: htmlMsg });

}};
```

Comment: This code is poorly organized. I’m not even gonna read it.

Comment: I have formatted the code ,could you please let me know if it readable?

Comment: no it is nott readable to me.

Comment: formatted again please check

Comment: Search on one of the regular volunteers here and any of their code is okay with me as long as it wasn't posted into a comment.

Comment: i have edited again based on the suggestions

Comment: Would you please advise, what `type` of question is "Question 5"?

Comment: Would you please advise, did you make a deliberate decision to create a function bound to the Form vs one bound to the linked sheet? And, if so, what was the rationale?

Comment: Related question: [How do I check for an empty/undefined/null string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/154059/1330560). Of the 54 answers, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/154068/1330560) is the favourite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to send an email on submission of a Google Form. But you need to test whether the value of a specific question (question 5) was answered (it is not a required field).

The following script should replace the script in the question.

- The script should be bound to the Form
- The script should be triggered by `onFormSubmit`

**Remarks**

- `thisQuestion5 = allQuestions[4]`

  - `allQuestions`: the number of item responses returned is equal to the number of questions (whether answered or not).
  - this is a zero-based array so the answer to question5 = `allQuestions[4]`
- `if (thisQuestion5 === "") {`

  - the item response values are returned as strings; so an unanswered question will be an empty string. It will NOT be a "null" value.
- **Binding: Form Vs Sheets**

  - there is something to be said for writing a script that is bound to the linked spreadsheet rather than the Form. The main benefit is that the `onFormSubmit` Sheets trigger returns the [actual responses](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) which can simplify the script, or at least improve trouble-shooting.

---

```
function getAnswer() {
  var allQuestions,
    L,
    thisQuestion5,
    number_of_submissions;

  number_of_submissions = FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponses().length;

  allQuestions = FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponses()[number_of_submissions-1].getItemResponses();

  L = allQuestions.length;

  thisSubmissionsAnswers = [];

  // get the answer to question 5
  thisQuestion5 = allQuestions[4] 
  Logger.log("question 5 = "+thisQuestion5+" with a length of "+thisQuestion5.length)
  // test if there was "no answer"
  if (thisQuestion5 === "") {
    Logger.log("Question 5 was not answered. It is an empty string. Assign a value of 'No Answer'")
    thisQuestion5 = "No Answer"
  }

  let htmlMsg = thisQuestion5
  
  if (thisQuestion5 === 'Incident Reported'){
      GmailApp.sendEmail('abc@gmail.com', 'Incident Reported', '', { htmlBody: htmlMsg })

  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion.This worked perfect ,so when a user dont enter anything in the form it does'nt fail and sends an email.