# Replace a null value for one of the questions in a Google Form with AppsScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-forms-api, py-appscript, rb-appscript

I have a requirement where I need to get the answer for  2 form questions in a Google Form and send the details in email.

Question 1 - is a mandatory field and it is a text field so there is no problem.

Question 2 - is an optional field (not mandatory) where they can upload documents like picture,pdf,word doc or excel. There is no text.

When answering the form, if I upload a document then I get the email with the document uploaded as a link to the drive.  But if I don't upload any document my below code is failing with the below error:
when no document uploaded how do I replace that doc with some message like "no document uploaded"

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Also, I want to know when there is no document uploaded how can I replace the link in the html email message  with something like "*No answer*"?

let htmlMsg = thisAnswer + "https://drive.google.com/file/d/" + thisAnswer2

Here is my current code:

```
function EmailForm() {
 var allQuestions,
 i, 
 itemType, 
 L, 
thisAnswer, 
Question1, 
Question2, 
itemType2, 
thisAnswer2, 
number_of_submissions;
 

number_of_submissions = FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponses().length;

allQuestions = FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponses()[number_of_submissions - 1].getItemResponses();

L = allQuestions.length;
thisSubmissionsAnswers = [];
  
  Question1 = allQuestions[0];
  
  itemType = Question1.getItem().getType();

  if (itemType === FormApp.ItemType.PAGE_BREAK) {

  };

  thisAnswer = Question1.getResponse().toString();//Get the answer
  Logger.log(thisAnswer);


  Question2 = allQuestions[2];//Get this question

  if (Question2 === "") {

    Question2 = "None"
  }
  else {
    itemType2 = Question2.getItem().getType();

    if (itemType2 === FormApp.ItemType.PAGE_BREAK) {

    };

    thisAnswer2 = Question2.getResponse().toString();//Get the answer
    Logger.log(thisAnswer2);

    
    let htmlMsg = thisAnswer + "https://drive.google.com/file/d/" + thisAnswer2

    if (thisAnswer === 'Yes') {
      GmailApp.sendEmail('abc@gmail.com', "Incident Reported", "", { htmlBody: htmlMsg });
    }

  };`
```

I am quite new to AppScript so please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace a null/blank in Google form response from Apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78018368/how-to-replace-a-null-blank-in-google-form-response-from-apps-script)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that StackOverflow is agnostic on the issue of helping with homework. But it's not asking too much to check if someone has already asked (and received an answer to)  the same question.

Comment: @Tedinoz  the post you refered works well if the value is just a string but for me  users will upload a file for question 2 ,so it is not able to recognize a null when users dont upload any document . it is failing at this point  when the users dont upload any document.Is there a way to fix this.                      
           itemType2 = Question2.getItem().getType();

Comment: Is it necessary that the apps script be bound to the Form?

Comment: i wrote the script bound to the form because whenever there is new submission email should be sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a Google Form and you want to send an email on submission of a form.

- the Form includes a non-mandator "File Upload" question.
- if the "File Upload" question is NOT answered, you want to "flag" this in your email.

**There are two types of `onFormSubmit` trigger.**

- a script bound to the Google Form
- a script bound to the linked Google Sheet
- each trigger has different [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).

There are circumstances where one type is preferred to the other. In this case, where specific Form values are required, a script bound to the Sheet is a better option because of the consistency of results:

- values are returned for **ALL** questions including those where the question is not answered.
- each value is returned as a **string** regardless of question-type.
- the value of an unanswered question will be an empty string.

The OP's script was written as as a script "bound to the Form".

The following answer is written as a script bound to the linked Google Sheet, and triggered by `onFormSubmit`.

---

```
function  sendEmail(e) {

  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))

  var values = e.values
  Logger.log(values)
  Logger.log("number of questions = "+values.length)
  var timeStamp = values[0]
  var q1 = values[1]
  var q2 = values[2]
  Logger.log("timestamp = "+timeStamp+", question#1 = "+q1+", question#2 = "+q2)

  if (q2 === ""){
    // the question wasn't answered, so set q2 = "Not Answered"
    q2 = "Not Answered"
    Logger.log("q2 wasn't answered. Value = "+q2)
  }
  else{
    // q2 was answered
    Logger.log("q2 was answered; the value = "+q2)
  }

}
```

---

**SAMPLE - Form Responses**

[image: responses]

---

**SAMPLE - Executions Log**

[image: executions]